# How InputStream really works while reading file from socket in java?

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, java-io, fileinputstream

I have a simple program which gets `BufferedInputStream` from URL and I have seen that while reading from the underlying stream, `read(bytes)` calls goes to `FileInputStream` from `BufferedInputStream` (so for this I convinced my self saying as at the other end of socket , it is actually a file may be that's why it goes to `FileInputStreams` (Please let me know if my assumptions are correct about this )).

When read happens in `FileInputStreams read()` method the "path" variable is set to the location of my class file from where the read call is being invoked , well this is very confusing to me as I was expecting the file's actual URL location here which I am downloading ..

Please help me understand these things and how actually read() happens from a remote file ??

```
 URL url = new URL("some url for downloading a file");
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
    FileOutputStream fis = new FileOutputStream(file);
    int size = 65536;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    int count;
    while ((count = bis.read(buffer, 0, size)) != -1) {
        fis.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }
    fis.close();
    bis.close();
```

Comment: Could you provide the code for where you create the streams, please, including the URL?  (Blank out of a bit of the URL if you need to, but give us the structure of it)

Comment: @BobJacobsen Updated.

Comment: So where's the FileInputStream you refer to in your question? And what's the "path" variable?  When you open e.g. a http: URL to read from a remote machine, there's not necessarily a file there.  Why are you trying to put that into a file metaphor?

Comment: Your "assumption" is not correct.  The fact that the other end of the socket happens to be a file, is unrelated to what happens locally to read the stream.

Comment: @BobJacobsen I basically debug the program and seen that the read calls goes to FileInputStream's read method at lower level and from there finally it goes to native system calls . Here by "path" variable I mean the parameter which presents in the FileInputStream's class from java.io package.

Comment: @deltamind106 can you please explain why the call goes to that specific implementation of InputStream class ? also can you please share some lights on the other part of the question ?

Comment: What's the URL?  Is it a file: or a http: or something else?

Comment: @BobJacobsen Its a http url .

Comment: @Dipanakar A call to read via an object of type BufferedInputStream cannot call the implementation of read that is defined by type FileInputStream.  The two types are unrelated (except that they share a common ancestor InputStream in the class hierarchy).  What makes you think this is happening?

Comment: I think you're trying to do something that it doesn't make sense to do.  How the Java librarians decided to implement the URL.getStream() method is an implementation issue that can change from version to version, from machine to machine.  On macOS, there's a lot of similarity between reading a file (once that's set up) and reading from a network socket (once that's set up), but the rest of those operations is very different. Maybe Java used some common code, maybe it didn't.

Comment: @deltamind106 I debug the sample program which I have attached in the question and trust me it took me to FileInputStreams read method just after I reach read method in BufferedInputStream.  This is the method from FileInputStream >>      private native int readBytes(byte b[], int off, int len) throws IOException; . Can u please debug the program which I attached here.

Comment: @BobJacobsen I didn't get your point properly . Can u please elaborate ??

Comment: @deltamind106 Maybe what u r saying is correct may the call went to fileInputStream class for something else , but where is then the final gateway endpoint from java socket side by this i mean which class actually calls the native method to read the actual download file's buffer (basically where exactly the buffer sync happens )...?